# Trying to run consecutive queries in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am creating a **temp** table

```sql
CREATE TABLE TMP_PRTimeSum AS 
SELECT DISTINCT p.employee,
       SUM(p.wage_amount) AS wage_sum,
       SUM(p.hours) AS hour_sum
```

I then want to do a select from that temp table and show the results.  I want to do it all in one query. It works if I run them as two separate queries.  Is there any way to do this in one query?

Comment: You can't. Besides, code you posted is invalid (missing GROUP BY clause; and then you'd remove DISTINCT as it becomes superfluous).

Comment: You should not be creating "temporary" tables like this in the first place.  You should create a Global Temporary Table (look it up) one time, outside of the application.  A  GTT gets a unique "instance" if the table for each session, so that its data is unique to the session, and disappears when the session ends.  Besides, why do you think you need to do it in one "query"?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE a
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
AS
select * from b;
```

(add where 1=0 too if you didn't want to initially populate it for the current session with all the data from b).

Comment: With `where 1 = 0` your table may get wrong data types.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It didn't occur to me

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do this in one query?

No, you need to use one DDL statement (`CREATE TABLE`) to create the table and one DML statement (`SELECT`) to query the newly created table.

---

If you want to be really pedantic then you could do it in a single PL/SQL statement:

```sql
DECLARE
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  
  v_employee VARCHAR2(20);
  v_wage     NUMBER;
  v_hours    NUMBER;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'CREATE TABLE TMP_PRTimeSum (employee, wage_sum, hour_sum) AS
       SELECT P.EMPLOYEE,
              SUM(P.WAGE_AMOUNT),
              SUM(P.HOURS)
       FROM   table_name p
       GROUP BY p.Employee';

  OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT * FROM TMP_PRTimeSum';
  
  LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO v_employee, v_wage, v_hours;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_employee || ', ' || v_wage || ', ' || v_hours);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=466265b852329c194cb5f628420b21ba)*

However, you are then wrapping the two SQL statements in a PL/SQL anonymous block so, depending on how you want to count it then it is either one composite statement, two SQL statements or three (2 SQL and 1 PL/SQL) statements.